# How should I bow this marking?

Tags: notation, bowing

I have done this dozens of times but still I forget it. How should I play , where the first note is tied to the second and third note as below:[image]

Comment: Welcome to Music.SE. It's difficult to understand what you're asking here, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a hooked bow. What you've drawn is two notes slurred and a phrasing mark over all three.
It's certainly possible that you'd want to play them all in the same bow direction, but not necessary.
There isn't a standard symbol for hooked bowing so far as I know (someone please correct me if I've missed it).  The composer might write in up- or down- bow markings if hooking is desired.